# Apache Kafka Storing Stateful data

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a scenario where i need to hold stateful data that is deliver very infrequently but is needed regularly by upstream application.  I only need to store the last update and am not interested in storing every update.  Can Kafka handle a scenario where it stores only latest value for a parameter?

Ex. dataset 1:

```
discards,0;errors,1;rate,32;ifspeed,10GB
```

dataset 2:

```
discards,0;errors,34;rate,38
```

dataset 3

```
discards,2;errors,0;rate,25
```

When the application pickups data from this topic it needs to include the ifspeed always.

Comment: *stores only latest value for a parameter* - are you familiar with or researched compacted topics?

Comment: I have not heard of "compacted topics", i will look into it.